# How to compare created_at timestamp with Carbon date In laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have orders table , I want to get orders that have been created at this month only (delivery process happens at the same day).

I want to compare between the carbon date which refers to this current month with the created_at field of type timestamps for orders.

This is my attempt:

```
$month = Carbon::today();
        $currentMont = $month->month;
        $thisMonthOrders = Order::where('place_id',$id)->where('stage',9)->whereDate('created_at',$currentMont)->get();

        dd($thisMonthOrders);
```

The output that it gives me is an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `MONTH` function in MySQL, along with a whereRaw:

```
$thisMonthOrders = Order::where('place_id',$id)
->where('stage',9)
->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMont])
->get();
```

However, you'll have issues when you have multiple years, unless you also add in a YEAR check. You might have better luck with `whereBetween` instead.

```
$start = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$end = $start->copy()->endOfMonth();

$thisMonthOrders = Order::where('place_id',$id)
    ->where('stage',9)
    ->whereBetween('created_at',[$start, $end])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Or add `AND YEAR(created_at) = ?`

Comment: Correct. I'm not sure on the performance difference between `where between` and checking `month`/`year` specifically, though.

Comment: A function would prevent the use of an index if one exists on `created_at`. However if there's no index it shouldn't really make a difference.